# How to create a matrix progressively in R

Tags: r, statistics

I start with a vector

`x <- c(1:8)`

of eight components in R. So this vector looks like:

`[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`

Then I compute a new value for x which I would like to store in rows. So, for intance, after three steps I would have a Matrix which is 3 times 8 and each row would contain the values for x for each step. That is

`[,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    2     3    4    5    6    7    8
[2,]    9    10    11   12   13   14   15   16
[3,]    17   18    19   20   21   22   23   24`

where in the second and Third row we have added the new values, one by one.

Any suggestion how to do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you also paste your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
n <- 3
matrix(x+ rep(seq(0,length.out=n, by=8), each=length(x)), nrow=n, byrow=TRUE)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
#[2,]    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
#[3,]   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24
```

#### Update

If you need double `for` loops (it would have been better if you showed the code you used)

```
v1 <- seq(0, length.out=n, by=8)
m1 <- matrix(ncol=length(x), nrow=n)
for(i in 1:n){
for(j in seq_along(x)){
   m1[i,j] <- v1[i]+x[j]
  }
 }

m1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
#[2,]    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
#[3,]   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24
```

Comment: I see, it seems to work. The only problem is that, each element in the row is being generated progressively. I am inside two "for's" one for the rows (step i) and the other one for the columns (value j), how could I do this? maybe I need an auxiliary vector?